# If record exits then check for column value sql

Tags: sql

I am new to sql and I want to write a query where it will return a count of Address if record exists then values of city should be "Nagpur". But users are allowed to have 0 address.

Address

```
---------------------
UserId AddressId City
1      101       Delhi
2      102       Nagpur
---------------------
```

User

```
---------------------
UserId 
1      
2     
3
---------------------
```

Expectation is to return non zero count for user id 2 and 3.

Comment: The question is poorly explained:
- FIRST: What do you mean with  "if record exists then values of city should be "Nagpur" "?
- SECOND: A Left join could be helpful...

Comment: Isn't "Expectation is to return non zero count for user id **1** and 3"?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
 U.UserID,
 COUNT(A.UserId)
FROM
 User U
 Join
 Address A ON U.UserId = A.UserId
GROUP BY
 U.UserID
```